# Get layer's unit of measurement as string in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyqgis

I'm writing a plugin where once a layer is selected in a combo box, it shows the layer's linear unit of measurement (meters, feet, etc.) in a QLineEdit box.

```
def Function(self):
    currLyr = self.cmbLyrSelect.currentLayer()
    currLyrUnit = currLyr.sourceCrs().mapUnits()
    self.linEditBox.setText(str(currLyrUnit))
```

This works and `mapUnits()` return a  `0`, which is [meters](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsUnitTypes.html#qgis.core.QgsUnitTypes.DistanceMeters) as the layer is projected. So, to get `meters` as string, I use instead

```
    self.linEditBox.setText(str(currLyrUnit.encodeUnit()))
```

But QGIS returns an Attribute Error saying `'DistanceUnit' object has no attribute 'encodeUnit'`.

What's the **correct syntax** in using `encodeUnit()`?

`sourceCrs()` https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsCoordinateTransform.html?highlight=sourcecrs#qgis.core.QgsCoordinateTransform.sourceCrs

`mapUnits()` https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#qgis.core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.mapUnits

`DistanceUnit()` https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsUnitTypes.html#qgis.core.QgsUnitTypes.DistanceUnit

`encodeUnit()` https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsUnitTypes.html#qgis.core.QgsUnitTypes.encodeUnit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it with the following code :

```py
QgsUnitTypes.encodeUnit(self.cmbLyrSelect.currentLayer().crs().mapUnits())
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This worked `self.linEditBox.setText(QgsUnitTypes.encodeUnit(currLyrUnit))`